# update a specific tab of an accordionpanel from inside a dialog

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am implementing somebody's ui design. I have an accordion panel. I iterate through the components and display one tab for each. I then attach a dialog for the elements inside the tab. Once a dialog is closed, I need to update the values within the tab it was opened from. How can know which component "activeTab" to update on return ? PF 3.5 and IE 8.

Once the dialog opens up, the user adds entries and in the tab, I display the total of the entries once they close the dialog. I do not want to refresh all of the tabs or the form and just the tab they entered the entries for. Reason I am trying to avoid refresh is that IE is not really too happy with all the refreshing going on. What do I update on close button of dialog ":mainForm:accordionTab:oneTab" ?

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
     <ui:include src="dialog.xhtml"></ui:include>
     <p:accordionPanel value="#{bean.list}" var="elem" id="accordionTab">
        <p:tab id="oneTab">
             ... other stuff
             <p:commandButton 
                 oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) {dialog.show();}"
                 action="#{bean.getDialogDetails()}"
                 update=":mainForm:dialogId"/>
        </p:tab>
     </p:accordionPanel>
</h:form>

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

   private final List<Division> list= new ArrayList<>();

   private Account currentAccount;

   public Bean() {
   }

   @ManagedProperty(value = "#{dialog}")
   private Dialog dialog;

   public void setDialog(Dialog dialog) {
    this.dialog = dialog;
   }
}
```

Adding the bean per request.

Comment: post your managed bean code.

Comment: Could you explain a little further as its bit vague to get what you're after sir !

Comment: Following code is used for update 1 accordion item from popup in RichFaces: `<a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" execute="@none" render="bannerAccordionItem" />`. Similar mechanism should work in PrimeFaces too.

Comment: Problem is the render piece. When the ok button in dialog is clicked, I have to render the tab but since there are many tab entries. I do not know which one to render.